# How to Show Actual Field of Reference Field in Flask-Admin?

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-admin, flask-mongoengine

I'm currently setting up Flask-Admin with mongoengine, and when rendering columns of a Model which are ReferenceFields as well as Embedded fields, I'm getting back "{ObjectType} Object" for those fields.

For example, I have these models

```
class Customer(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()

class Item(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    name = db.StringField()

class Order(db.DynamicDocument):
    customer = db.ReferenceField('Customer')
    items = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Item))
    total = db.IntField()
```

But when this model is rendered by this view:

```
class OrderView(ModelView):
    column_list = ['id', 'customer', 'total', 'items']
```

I am getting back this table:

[image]

How do I get "Customer Object" to render as something useful, like Customer.Id, or Customer.name, and same for the Order.items field?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, but eventually arrived to a solution.

When you're defining the class for your model (the one that is going to be later referenced) you should override the **str**() method and request the string representation for this class to be any field you want.

```
class Customer(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```